# Inequality regarding weak solution of $-\operatorname{div} (a(\nabla u))=f$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

$\Omega$ bounded, $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $u\in H^{1,2} (\Omega)$ a weak solution of 
$$-\operatorname{div}(a(\nabla u))=f$$
with $a:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ lipschitz continous and there exists a $c_0$ with
$$(a(p_1)-a(p_2))\cdot(p_1-p_2 \geq c_0|p_1-p_2|^2$$
for $p_1,p_2 \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

I want to show now there is

i) a $C>0$ so that,
$$||\nabla u||_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C(||u||_{L^2(\Omega)}+||f||_{L^2(\Omega)}+||a(0)||_{L^2(\Omega)})$$

ii) $u\in H^{2,2}(\Omega ')$ for all $\Omega '\subset \subset \Omega$ and there exists a $C>0$ 
$$||D^2 u||_{L^2(\Omega')} \leq C(||u||_{L^2(\Omega)}+||f||_{L^2(\Omega)}+||a(0)||_{L^2(\Omega)})$$

How does one see that? I even think its wrong even though it should be easy to prove. Anyone can help?

Comment: The first inequality can be obtained by testing the equation with $u$, put in some zeros (literally), use the monotonicity of $a$